# How to put a date to only a specific cell containing a specific data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have in a sheet about 150000 rows containing name and ID. The ID`s are between 1 and 78 and I need to select only 50 of each ID and write a date.

Is there any formula to do it or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you're asking for. Please read this https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, and then edit your question

Comment: This may seem clear to you, but it is really unclear to me.   For example, what criteria do you use to select a valid match for each ID.  Write a date for each of the 50? And that is just the start of what you need to provide.  You need to provide a numerical example.